# How command Bulk Rename Utility to disregard case when removing characters or words?

Tags: batch-rename

I see nothing in red box for case matching or sensitive!

I want it remove bunch characters or words regardless of upper or lower case!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That option doesn't have a case sensitivity setting, but you can enter variations of a letter or word. For instance, to remove both `Test` and `test` in some selected file names, you would type `Test test` in the `Words` field:

*ex. Remove `Test` and `test` via `Remove (5)`*

[image: Bulk Rename Utility - Screenshot 1]

You can do the same thing for letters in the `Chars` field (e.g. use `Tt` to remove both capital and lowercase `T` in the selected file names).

---

*The drawback to this approach is that you must type both the upper and lowercase versions of a letter or all the specific variations of a word you wish to remove to have each variation be affected.*

---

Alternately, if you simply want a case-insensitive way to replace a single letter or a group of characters (e.g. a word or phrase), you can use the `Replace` field in the `Replace (3)` option and simply leave the `With` field blank:

*ex. Remove `Test` and `test` via `Replace (3)`*

[image: Bulk Rename Utility - Screenshot 2]

Of course, make certain that `Match Case` is unchecked.

---

*The drawback to this approach is that you can only affect one letter or one specific group of characters (e.g. a word or phrase) at a time.*

---